# Initialising OAuth WebClient Bean in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have a WebApp JSP project deployed on Weblogic 12 as a WAR.

My gradle build includes mvc and webflux:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.2.RELEASE'
implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.3.2.RELEASE")
implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:2.3.2.RELEASE")
implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.3.2.RELEASE")
```

I am trying to configure OAuth2 to use client_credentials flow from my client JSP application.

I need the @Controller class to use WebClient and propagate the access token to a Resource Server.

My Bean to create the WebClient is seen below.

```
@Bean
public ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository getRegistration() {
    ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
            .withRegistrationId("ei-gateway")
            .tokenUri("https://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.net/auth/oauth/v2/token")
            .clientId("xxx-xxxx-43e9-a407-xxxxx")
            .clientSecret("xxxxxx-3d21-4905-b6e5-xxxxxxxxxx")
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .build();
    return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
}


@Bean
public WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations, ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients) {

    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations, authorizedClients);
    oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
    return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(oauth)
            .defaultHeader("accept", "application/json")
            .defaultHeader("content-type", "application/json")
            .defaultHeader("environment", environment)
            .filter(logRequest())
            .filter(logResponse())
            .build();
}
```

However I get the following error during compile:

```
Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository' type.
Beans:
clientRegistrationRepository   (ReactiveOAuth2ClientConfigurations.class) 
getRegistration   (WebSecurityConfiguration.java)
```

However when I uncomment out the getRegistration Bean method and configure the oauth client registration via the web.xml, then when deploying the application I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}:org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I see from the ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration source code that the Reactive OAuth2 Auto Configuration is not run when ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration.NonServletApplicationCondition is set.

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@AutoConfigureBefore(ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(OAuth2ClientProperties.class)
@Conditional(ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration.NonServletApplicationCondition.class)
@ConditionalOnClass({ Flux.class, EnableWebFluxSecurity.class, ClientRegistration.class })
@Import({ ReactiveOAuth2ClientConfigurations.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class,
        ReactiveOAuth2ClientConfigurations.ReactiveOAuth2ClientConfiguration.class })
public class ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration {
}
```

Can anyone suggest a course of action? Is is possible to manually configure the ReactiveOAuth2ClientConfiguration?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form what I understand `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` is not available since you are not using a reactive stack, and here's how you can set up WebClient to be used in a Servlet environment.

Setup application properties so Spring autowires `ClientRegistrationRepository` and `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` for you.

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my-oauth-provider.token-uri=https://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.net/auth/oauth/v2/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ei-gateway.client-id=xxx-xxxx-43e9-a407-xxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ei-gateway.client-xxxxxx-3d21-4905-b6e5-xxxxxxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ei-gateway.provider=my-oauth-provider
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ei-gateway.scope=read,write
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ei-gateway.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
```

Setup configuration to indicate that your application needs to act as an oauth2 Client

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.oauth2Client();
     }
}
```

Expose WebClient bean configured to use client credentials

```
@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
        ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                    .clientCredentials()
                    .build();

    DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                    clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    return authorizedClientManager;
}


@Bean
WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager) {
    ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
            new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                    oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager);
    
    // default registrationId - Only if you are not using the webClient to talk to different external APIs
   oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("ei-gateway");
    
    return WebClient.builder()
      .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
      .build();
}
```

Now you can use WebClient in your code to access external protected resources.

references:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2client
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2Client-webclient-servlet
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#defaulting-the-authorized-client

This set up worked for me when the application is not configured as a resource server, I had to use a different configuration when the application needs to use WebClient, but also configured to be a resource server.